# How can I get Breeze to return HttpResponse 401 when the user isn't authorized for the query?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, authorization, breeze

How can I know it a user is not authorized to do a Breeze query?

I've added the `Authorize` attribute to a query of my Breeze controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class GamesController : ApiController
{
    //...
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IQueryable<Game> Games()
    {
        // return query from EF
    }
}
```

When I query this from javascript with Breeze, I get a HttpResponse of 200 and inside is the HTML of the login screen. I'd like to know when the user isn't authorized, and then handle this in javascript (and show whatever HTML I want at that moment).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further investigation, I believe this has nothing to do with Breeze. It is ASP.NET (MVC) that's responsible for this behavior. It returns a 302 Redirect when the user isn't authorized.

The way to work around this, is to hook into the behavior and make ASP.NET return a 401. But we only want to do this on an AJAX request.

The details are in [this blogpost](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Handling-Authorization-Failures-for-AJAX-Requests-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx), but it comes down to an `IHttpModule` that does changes the statuscode of the response:

```
if (true.Equals(context.Items["RequestWasNotAuthorized"]) && request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    response.StatusCode = 401;
    response.ClearContent();
}
```

and a custom attribute instead of ASP.NET's Authorize attribute:

```
public class AjaxAwareAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["RequestWasNotAuthorized"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You then just need to check the response for a 401 at the client side.